# Given a sum of two elements in an int array, how to find their smallest indexes?

Tags: java, arrays, indexing, sum

I want to return an **array of 2 integers**, **containing the indexes of a pair of integers** in the array **whose sum is k**.

```
int[] numbers = new int[]{1, 5, 8, 1, 2};
int k = 13;
```

I have done this method :

```
public int[] findSumPair(int[] numbers, int k){
   
    int[] pairs = new int[2];

    for(int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++){
        for(int j = i + 1; j < numbers.length; j++){
            if (numbers[i] + numbers[j] == k){
                pairs = new int[]{i, j};

               if (numbers[i] + numbers[j] != k){
                   pairs = new int[]{0, 0};
               }
            }
        }
    }
    return pairs;
}
```

With previous array and sum it works & returns:

```
[1,2]
```

For example with this:

```
int[] numbers = new int[]{1, 5, 0, 1, 2, 7, 8, 6};
int k = 13;
```

I should have:

```
[1,6] // But I get [5,7]
```

How can I, in case there are several possible pairs whose sum is equal to the target, return the pair with the lowest left index?

And in the case of 2 pairs with the same left index, go for the pair with the lowest right index?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: The final ```return``` case after the main loop should probably not return ```pairs``` directly since that will always be wrong, but some default like ```return new int[]{0, 0};```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume a return of `[n,m]` is an valid output where `n`<>`m` and `m` > 0. Assume a return of `[0,0]` is an exception output indicates the pair is not found.

There are some mistake in your function:

```java
    public int[] findSumPair(int[] numbers, int k) {

        int[] pairs = new int[2];

        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < numbers.length; j++) {
                if (numbers[i] + numbers[j] == k) {
                    // if a pair is found, you could stop looking anymore
                    pairs = new int[] { i, j };

                    // unreachable statement
                    if (numbers[i] + numbers[j] != k) {
                        pairs = new int[] { 0, 0 };
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return pairs;
    }
```

Firstly, if you want to find the smallest index, once you found a matched pair, you could break the for-loop. Since you start searching from the left, the first match must be the smallest. No matter now hard the program try, the next result is not the smallest.

Secondly, I think you try to set a false case condition to return `[0,0]` if no pair is found. However, the condition is contradict to its outer if condition. That is a unreachable statement. You can put that at the very end of the function since when we reach that part, the searching is already completed. I modified the function as:

```java
    public int[] findSumPair(int[] numbers, int k) {

        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < numbers.length; j++) {
                if (numbers[i] + numbers[j] == k) {
                    // quit immediately
                    return new int[] { i, j };
                }
            }
        }
        // if we reach here, no pair is found
        return new int[2];
    }
```

the `main()`

```java
        int[] result = main.findSumPair(new int[] { 1, 5, 8, 1, 2 }, 13);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result));

        result = main.findSumPair(new int[] { 1, 5, 0, 1, 2, 7, 8, 6 }, 13);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result));

        result = main.findSumPair(new int[] { 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1 }, 2);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result));

        result = main.findSumPair(new int[] { 1, 2, 2, 2, 4, 3 }, 7);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result));

        result = main.findSumPair(new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 9, 9, 9, 4 }, 5);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result));
```

console output

```
[1, 2]
[5, 7]
[0, 5]
[4, 5]
[0, 6]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now I have [1,6] for int[] numbers = new int[]{1, 5, 0, 1, 2, 7, 8, 6} & [0, 0] if no pair found

Answer (score 1):

Since you are scanning left to right, you can just `return` after finding the first match i.e., replacing

```
           if (numbers[i] + numbers[j] != k){
               pairs = new int[]{0, 0};
           }
```

with `return pairs`.

Answer (score 0):

@bui

I have to keep this part:

```
if (numbers[i] + numbers[j] != k) {
    pairs = new int[]{0, 0};
}
```

Because:

```
[0, 0]
```

Must be returned if no pair equal to k is found

Comment: You can just replace the `return pairs;` at the end with `return new int[]{0,0};` because if the code has reached that stage without returning, then there's no valid pair and you can safely return the default `{0,0}` pair